# Google Chrome 1920x1080 issue?

Tags: google-chrome, resolution

I have been using my plasma tv as the screen for my computer at 1024x768 resolution. As a result I have gotten used to viewing everything in that resolution. Now I have plugged back in my normal computer monitor at 1920x1080 and when I open Chrome the websites don't seem right. Here is an example:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFAbo.png]

Is there supposed to be so much white space on the sides of the websites? Or am I just forgetting what it is supposed to look like?

**Edit**
I have just discovered that some likes like reddit and youtube seem to use the entirety of the screen so i'm inclined to think that this is how it is supposed to look.

Comment: Yup. And its *terrible*.  I run a 4k display and many sites only use 1/3 of the page. Mobile modes actually work better since they are designed to run on varying resolutions.

Comment: Thanks for that, I just got so used to seeing everything nice and zoomed in haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### I'm inclined to think that this is how it is supposed to look.

You are correct in your thinking.

That particular site http://www.news.com.au/ is designed appear with white space either side of the page content.

If you look at the page source (I used Firefox Developer Tools) you can see that the content of the page has a width of 1000 px (pixels):

```
#page {
    background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: left;
    width: 1000px;
}
```

If you resize the browser so that the browser content width (ie not including the Windows Frame) is < 1000 px then a horizontal scrollbar is added to the page.

Answer (score 1):

The site is intentionally designed to look like that on wide displays. This is usually due to either being a legacy site without responsive design or as a design choice due to the difficultly of filling a wide screen with the kind and amount of content that is easy to parse visually.